# Glow around transparent image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, png

If I have a png with a tranparent background, is it possible to add a glow type of effect around ONLY the NON-transparent part of the png with jQuery or css?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878162/possible-to-create-a-css-shadow-on-transparent-background-png-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a copy of the image behind the image and use CSS3 filter on the copy. Like this:

```
filter: blur(6px) opacity(0.15);
```

..if that is the effect you are looking for.

Comment: My Q was a duplicate, sorry :( This was what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878162/possible-to-create-a-css-shadow-on-transparent-background-png-image