# Sub-styling a geometrical shape inside of a div in HTML5 / CSS

Tags: html, css

Assume I have this image, which is a background of a div:

[image]

Assume the div is:

```
<div id="my-roulette-button">
    <!-- content would be here -->
</div>
```

styled like this:

```
#my-roulette-button {
    width: 286px;
    height: 286px;
    background: url('myimage.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

What I want to do is style the inner "button". The "button" I'm talking about is the inner -wooden- button-like circle with the "GIRAR" label (which is part of the image).

**Even if I put the shadow in another image, and another DOM element** I'm facing the same problem: styling a circle (instead of styling a squared, containing, region).

My **question** is: how could I style the inner circle? which element/styles should I apply? If it is possible, my intention is to:

- apply a :hover
- apply an ng-click (angular)
- apply a cursor pointer

I don't need help on how to do these 3 stylings, but **how to detect a circle and apply styles to it**.

Is it possible?

Comment: No. Just put it in the image. Here is the closest thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12921987/2101267

Comment: Doesn't address the issue I'm asking for. The issue is not about the shadow, but about a circular element in which apply a cursor:pointer and a ng-click handler