# CSS drop shadow on a .png image issue

Tags: html, css, image, shadow

I have a question that drives me nuts.
When I use **box-shadow** on an .png image, everything works normally although it forms a square around the image. To solve this we can use **drop-shadow**, which indeed follows the form of the image. However I can move the shadow left, right, up & down making it more or less blurred. But I can't find out how to spread the shadow! It seems like the 4th value cancels everything out of shadow.

The box shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px 150px rgba(39,21,6,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px 150px rgba(39,21,6,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px 150px rgba(39,21,6,1);
```

The drop shadow:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 130px 150px rgba(39,21,6,1));
```

Comment: The 4th value (spread) is not supported by most browsers

Comment: The 4th value (spread) is not supported by most browsers

Answer (score 0):

The question you've asked has multiple, popular answers in another thread! :)

[Drop shadow for PNG image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css)