# How can I use box-shadow comma separated values with filter: drop-shadow?

Tags: css

This question [Drop shadow for PNG image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css) almost gives me what I need - a true drop shadow to a PNG image, instead of a box shadow. But I also need to use the following comma separated value:

`0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)`

How do I achieve this using filter: drop-shadow?

Comment: if they are only 2, add another wrapper with the second shadow

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you write an example? What would adding another wrapper look like?

Comment: a simple `div` around your image