# How to filter only the edges of visible parts of the alpha png image?

Tags: css, filter

[image]
What I tried with css or svg filter applied to whole image, not only edges of visible areas.

```css
body{
  background:blue
  }
img{
  width:300px;
  /* these did not worked as intented */
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px white; */
  
  /* filter: blur(10px) */
  
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/b/126-1268896_megan-fox-png-image-megan-fox-transparent-png.png">
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css
The drop-shadow-filter from this answer should still work.

Comment: not actually, that applies out of image, what I need is edge of inside image.

Comment: The drop-shadow property will work for casting shadows around the visible edges of your png. Blurring only the corners is not possible via css. But any decent image-editing software could help you with that.